# slickgrid validate column with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, slickgrid

There is a simple sample with column validation:

```
    function requiredFieldValidator(value) {
      if (value == null || value == undefined || !value.length) {
        return {valid: false, msg: "This is a required field"};
      } else {
        return {valid: true, msg: null};
      }
    }
```

and to validate column it is just needed to put this option: `validator: requiredFieldValidator`

But how can I use regex function if I need to pass extra parameter - regex string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you cannot pass more parameters into the `validator` method, however you can easily edit the source to allow it.

in `slick.editors.js` look for:

```
this.validate = function () {
  if (args.column.validator) {
    var validationResults = args.column.validator($input.val());
    if (!validationResults.valid) {
      return validationResults;
    }
  }

  return {
    valid: true,
    msg: null
  };
};
```

**change:** `var validationResults = args.column.validator($input.val());`

**to:** `var validationResults = args.column.validator($input.val(), $input);`

this will change your validator method signature to something like:

```
function requiredFieldValidator(value, input)
```

With that, you can get whatever attributes you want out of input with `input.attr('validation-expression')` or `input.data...` or whatever.

Comment: Of course, you could edit that to pass anything you want. Like adding a validation settings object to args.column somewhere and passing that into args.column.validator's second parameter instead of $input.

Comment: did not get it. There are standard validators in`slick.editors.js` . Do I need to specify my own ? and how code will look like instead of `validator: requiredFieldValidator`

Comment: By default, slickGrid only passes the value of the input into a custom validator method, so `args.column.validator($input.val());` is currently only passing the value into your `requiredFieldValidator`. You code would still look like `validator: requiredFieldValidator`, but that would reference `function requiredFieldValidator(value, input)`

You would want the regex defined as an attribute in the input first.

Comment: and how can I specify `regex` attribute for different column different regex string ?

Answer (score 6):

The best way to approach this, in my view anyways, is to code your own editor which you'll add into `slick.editor.js` as another new custom editor. This file is made for that too. I did implement the regex test and it works great.

Here's my new editor which is not only working for Regex but also for various condition types, for example an option of `min:2` would required a minimum number of 2, while a `minLength:2` would required the input to be a String of at least 2 chars, etc... Now for the one you're really looking for, that would be in my code definition the `pattern` type.
So basically, you'll have to include this code inside the `slick.editor.js` :

```
ConditionalCellEditor : function(args) {            
    var $input;
                var defaultValue;
                var scope = this;
    var condObj = null;

                this.init = function() {
                        $input = $("<INPUT type='text' class='editor-text' />")
                                .appendTo(args.container)
                                .bind("keydown.nav", function(e) {
                                        if (e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.LEFT || e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT) {
                                                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                        }
                                })
                                .focus()
                                .select();
                };

                this.destroy = function() {
                        $input.remove();
                };

                this.focus = function() {
                        $input.focus();
                };

                this.getValue = function() {
                        return $input.val();
                };

                this.setValue = function(val) {
                        $input.val(val);
                };

                this.loadValue = function(item) {
                        defaultValue = item[args.column.field] || "";
                        $input.val(defaultValue);
                        $input[0].defaultValue = defaultValue;
                        $input.select();
                };

                this.serializeValue = function() {
                        return $input.val();
                };

                this.applyValue = function(item,state) {
                        item[args.column.field] = state;
                };

                this.isValueChanged = function() {
                        return (!($input.val() == "" && defaultValue == null)) && ($input.val() != defaultValue);
                };

                this.validate = function() {
        var condObj = args.column.editorOptions;
        var returnMsg = null;
        var returnValid = true;

        if(typeof condObj.min != 'undefined') {

            if( parseFloat($input.val()) < parseFloat(condObj.min) ) {
                returnMsg = "Value should not be less then "+condObj.min;
                returnValid = false;
            }
        }
        if(typeof condObj.max != 'undefined') {
            if( parseFloat($input.val()) > parseFloat(condObj.max) ) {
                returnMsg = "Value should not be over "+condObj.max;
                returnValid = false;
            }
        }
        if(typeof condObj.minLength != 'undefined') {

            if($input.val().length < condObj.minLength) {
                returnMsg = "Value length should not be less then "+condObj.minLength;
                returnValid = false;
            }
        }
        if(typeof condObj.maxLength != 'undefined') {
            if($input.val().length > condObj.maxLength) {
                returnMsg = "Value length should not be over "+condObj.maxLength;
                returnValid = false;
            }
        }
        if(typeof condObj.pattern != 'undefined') {
            if( condObj.pattern.test($input.val()) != true ) {
                returnMsg = (condObj.msg) ? condObj.msg : "Value is invalid following a regular expression pattern";
                returnValid = false;
            }
        }               
        if(typeof condObj.required != 'undefined') {
            if($input.val().length == "" && condObj.required) {
                returnMsg = "Required field, please provide a value";
                returnValid = false;
            }
        }

        // Now let's return our boolean results and message if invalid
        return {
            valid: returnValid,
            msg: returnMsg
        }
                };

                this.init();
},
```

Then inside my SlickGrid column definition I'm calling that new editor which I defined and passing some options which I decided to pass into an `editorOptions` as an Object and that gives me more flexibility to add any options I want, pattern, msg, minLength, etc... all at one. My example is for an email regex pattern validation.

```
columns1 = [
...
{id:"email", field:"email", name:"Em@il", width:145, editor:ConditionalCellEditor, editorOptions:{pattern:/^([0-9a-zA-Z]+([_.-]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*@[0-9a-zA-Z]+[0-9,a-z,A-Z,.,-]*(.){1}[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/, msg:"Must be a valid email"} },
...];
```

And voilà, works like a charm!!!
I'm barely using the `editor:TextCellEditor` anymore, since my new `ConditionalCellEditor` editor gives me a lot more flexibility. Hope it helps and let me know how it goes...

Answer (score 1):

In order to extend the answer of @mike-gwilt, you can use the [cellAttrs](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Column-Options) column options to specify (in your column definition) the regular expressions and the message to report, like this:

```
... { id: "columnId", name: "columnName", validator: RegexValidator, cellAttrs: {"reg":"^\\d{1,2}$", "msg": "The value should be a number of two digits."} ...
```

Then the html generated looks something like this:

```
<div class="slick-cell l9 r9 active editable selected" reg="^\d{1,3}$" msg="The value should be a number of two digits."><input type="text" class="editor-text" value=""></div>
```

Finally, as you can access the input element inside your validation function, define it like this:

```
 function RegexValidator(value, input) {
    var msg = input.parent().attr('msg');
    var reg = new RegExp(input.parent().attr('reg'));
    if (!reg.exec(value)) {
        return { valid: false, msg: msg};
    } else {
        return { valid: true, msg: null };
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This was very helpful.  I am creating different input types for every type of possible entry - email, phone, zip and so forth.
To do this with JSON, you have to modify your slick.grid.js file to evaluate the entries to make them an object call.

```
if (d) {
  if(m.formatter){
    m.formatter=eval(m.formatter)
    } // make it an object call instead of string

if(m.editor) {
    m.editor=eval(m.editor)
    }

if(m.editorOptions) {
    m.editorOptions=eval(m.editorOptions)
    }
```

}

Make your JSON columns have this update:

```
\"editor\": \"Slick.Editors.Conditional\", 
\"editorOptions\": 
   {\"pattern\":\"email\", \"msg\":\"Must be a valid email\",  \"required\":\"1\"}
```

Make youre slick.editors.js look like this:

```
(function ($) {
 $.extend(true, window, {
  "Slick": {
  "Editors": {
  "Conditional": Conditional, 

inside -> function Conditional(args){

if(typeof condObj.pattern != 'undefined') {
    if(condObj.pattern=='email'){
        pattern=/^([0-9a-zA-Z]+([_.-]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*@[0-9a-zA-Z]+[0-9,a-z,A-Z,.,-]*(.){1}[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/;
        val=$input.val();
      if(pattern.test(val) != true && val!='')  {
           returnMsg = (condObj.msg) ? condObj.msg : "Value is invalid";
           returnValid = false;
      }
 } 
}
if(!returnValid){
   alert(returnMsg)
}
```