# Adding a custom column property in SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, regex, properties, slickgrid

I want to add a custom column property to some of my columns in SlickGrid. I have a custom editor that uses regex to validate the input. I would like to add a regex statement property to my columns so that I can use the same editor for each of them and just grab the unique regex statement from them column.
I want something like this for the columns:

```
var columns = [{ id: "id", name: "#", field: "id", cssClass: "cell-title", resizeable: true, sortable: true },
           { id: "upc", name: "UPC", field: "upc", resizable: true, sortable: true, editor: regexValidationEditor, regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,20}$/ },
           { id: "price", name: "Price", field: "price", resizable: true, sortable: true, editor: regexValidationEditor, regex: /^\d*\.?\d{0,3}$/ }];
```

Then if I could do something like this in my validate function:

```
function regexValidationEditor(args) {
    var $value;
    var inputBox = "<INPUT class='customInput' type=text />";
    var scope = this;

    this.init = function () {
        $value = $(inputBox)
        .appendTo(args.container);

        scope.focus();
    };

    this.validate = function () {
        if (!args.column.regex.test($value.val())) {
            return { valid: false, msg: "Invalid Data Entry" };
        }
        return { valid: true, msg: null };
    };

    this.init();
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, but it's along the lines of what I want to do.

Comment: I think each column record should contain a record-descriptive message if the validation fails.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question properly, but are you looking for a Regex editor/validator? If that is what you are looking for, then please look at the answer I made to a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/9301137  ... if that is not it, then could you please explain a little more. Hope that helps. You can always vote at the other answer, or I could recopy the answer here too :)

Comment: @ghiscoding That's it! I wasn't sure how to access the custom fields if I put them into the column, but I see you got them via args.column.editorOptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column information goes in just as you define it, thus the custom property will be there. Supply all the necessary [editor functions](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.editors.js) and the validation will work.

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/37po0aqk/)

```
function Editor(args) {
  var $input, defaultValue;
  var scope = this;

  this.init = function () {
    $input = $("<INPUT type=text class='editor-text' />")
        .appendTo(args.container)
        .bind("keydown.nav", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.LEFT || e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    })
        .focus()
        .select();
  };

  this.validate = function () {
    if (!args.column.regex.test($input.val())) {
         
        return {
            valid: false,
            msg: "Invalid Data Entry"
        };
    }
    return {
        valid: true,
        msg: null
    };
  };

  this.applyValue = function (item, state) {
    item[args.column.field] = state;
  };

  this.destroy = function () {
    $input.remove();
  };

  this.focus = function () {
    $input.focus();
  };

  this.getValue = function () {
    return $input.val();
  };

  this.setValue = function (val) { 
    $input.val(val);
  };

  this.loadValue = function (item) {
    defaultValue = item[args.column.field] || "";
     
    $input.val(defaultValue);
    $input[0].defaultValue = defaultValue;
    $input.select();
 };

 this.serializeValue = function () {
    return $input.val();
 };

 this.isValueChanged = function () {
    return (!($input.val() == "" && defaultValue == null)) && ($input.val() != defaultValue);
 };

 scope.init();
}
```

Comment: That's it! I have to go through args.column to get the property.